# Is there away I can make this code to loop and select many workbooks at once? I need cell A1 copied to every line added

Tags: excel, vba

Every workbook I am trying to concatenate has its own PO reference on cell A1. I need to concatenate several workbooks with  its PO reference in each line. The code below works, but I need to select each workbook individually. Is there away to loop it?

```
Sub A_Get_Data_From_Files ()

Dim FileToOpen As Variant
Dim OpenBook As Workbook

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Browse for your File & Import Range", FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xls*), *xls*")
If FileToOpen <> False Then
Set OpenBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(FileToOpen)
        OpenBook.Sheets(1).Range("A7:K1000").Copy
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tester File").Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        OpenBook.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Copy
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tester File").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        OpenBook.Close False
        
    End If
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
'Fill blanks spaces under. A is where to copy and D the rows to count
 With Range("A2:A" & Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    .SpecialCells(xlBlanks).FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C"
    .Value = .Value
    
  End With
  
End Sub
```

Comment: `GetOpenFilename` has a `MultiSelect` parameter -  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.getopenfilename

Comment: If the workbooks reside in the same folder, you may use the method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72114015/3527297) with some modifications.

Comment: Unfurtunately it doesn't work for me. I need to be able to choose the range and add a column.